# Improving/editing JSON from CakePHP 2 for Ext-JS 4

Tags: php, json, cakephp, extjs

Ok guys, I've got this from CakePHP:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Worker' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'username' => 'davorlozic',
            'first_name' => 'Davor',
            'last_name' => 'Lozic',
            'active' => true,
            'created' => '2012-05-12 10:39:05',
            'modified' => '2012-05-12 10:39:05'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Worker' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'username' => 'markomarkovic',
            'first_name' => 'Marko',
            'last_name' => 'Markovic',
            'active' => true,
            'created' => '2012-05-12 10:39:20',
            'modified' => '2012-05-12 10:39:20'
        )
```

So, when I encode it with JSON_ENCODE I get this:

[image]

BUT I NEED TO GET THIS: HOW? (this shape, not these data)

```
{
    "success": true,
    "Workers": [
        {"id": 1, "name": 'Ed',    "email": "ed@sencha.com"},
        {"id": 2, "name": 'Tommy', "email": "tommy@sencha.com"}
    ]
}
```

Can I do something with the FIRST array? Some shifting or something? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

your current problem is that **CakePHP** and **ExtJS** use different data structures for read requests. You will probably later figure out that there are a lot more issues, and it can become quite tricky. I have had many **CakePHP** and **ExtJS** projects always facing these problems, it also gets really annoying to have to create custom **json** views for each request type and controller.

That's why I started together with some colleges **Bancha**, which automates all these things for you. The best place is to start at [banchaproject.org](http://banchaproject.org) and see the samples and docs.

For any questions feel free to write to **support@banchaproject.org**

Best regards
Roland